# Time Comparison in Nested For- Loop Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested

I have two lists that contain time stamps. I want to compare and use the time stamps to create a new list.

```
comp = ['2018-07-21,11:37:20', '2018-07-21,11:52:57', '2018-07-21,12:08:20', '2018-07-21,12:41:28', '2018-07-21,12:56:46', '2018-07-21,13:12:09', '2018-07-22,11:12:50', '2018-07-22,11:29:18', '2018-07-22,11:44:44', '2018-07-22,12:08:57', '2018-07-22,12:24:18', '2018-07-22,12:39:35']
startDate = ['2018-07-21,11:37:07', '2018-07-22,11:12:41']
```

I am trying to create

```
start = ['2018-07-21,11:37:07', '2018-07-21,11:37:07', '2018-07-21,11:37:07', '2018-07-21,11:37:07', '2018-07-21,11:37:07', '2018-07-21,11:37:07', '2018-07-22,11:12:41', '2018-07-22,11:12:41', '2018-07-22,11:12:41', '2018-07-22,11:12:41', '2018-07-22,11:12:41', '2018-07-22,11:12:41']
```

Which has the same length as `comp`, but uses the elements from `startDate`.  `start[i]` will be one of the elements from `startDate` depending on if  `comp[i]` is greater than or equal to `startDate`.

The code I have currently is:

```
start = []

for x in comp:
    for y in range(len(startDate)-1):
        if x >= startDate[y] and x < startDate[y+1]:
            start.append(startDate[y])`
```

but `start` only has a length of 6 (the first six elements that I am expecting)

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: you are comparing strings, not datetime.dateime's. that might work, or not. are you sure comparing the string-values is what you are after?

Comment: well - you are missing the `else:` case - that should happen if they do NOT match your if? currently nothing happens, so some do not make it inside your new list...

Comment: didn't you post this same question before, which got deleted?

Answer (score 2):

```
for x in comp:
        for y in range(len(startDate)-1):
            if x >= startDate[y] and x < startDate[y+1]:
                start.append(startDate[y])
            else:
                start.apped(startDate[y+1])
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
comp = ['2018-07-21,11:37:20', '2018-07-21,11:52:57', '2018-07-21,12:08:20', '2018-07-21,12:41:28', '2018-07-21,12:56:46', '2018-07-21,13:12:09', 
        '2018-07-22,11:12:50', '2018-07-22,11:29:18', '2018-07-22,11:44:44', '2018-07-22,12:08:57', '2018-07-22,12:24:18', '2018-07-22,12:39:35']
startDate = ['2018-07-21,11:37:07', '2018-07-22,11:12:41']

start = [startDate[0] if startDate[0]<x<startDate[1] else startDate[1] for x in comp]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start = [y if x>=y and x<startDate[startDate.index(y) + 1] else startDate[startDate.index(y) + 1] for y in startDate[:-1] for x in comp]
```